# Adding a blog functionality to your website without the use of databases? HTML5/CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, html, blogs, blogger

So I have a local website that I am developing and I was wondering if there is a way to create a blog functionality without creating a database and by using HTML5/CSS alone.

From searches around it doesnt seem possible, so maybe if I could embed the blog functionality from somewhere? i.e a blogging service that would allow my users to use my website but they are posting to a database somewhere else?

If I could do that, could you give me an example and what would be the method on doing it?

Thnanks

Comment: What do you mean by "blog functionality"?  Are you talking about embedding posts from a specific blogging website onto your website?

Comment: nop, I mean allowing users to submit comments on a post i wrote

Comment: So perhaps you are looking for some Facebook-like feature you may directly achieve by using Facebook APIs. Check [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments) out.

Answer (score -1):

I actually haven't tried this yet, but you could have a look at http://developer.wordpress.com/, particularly in the [API](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/) section. For example, if you look at the `GET /sites/$site/posts/` API, the doc summary says:

> Get a list of matching posts.

So one may use a query matching the pattern:

```
https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/en.blog.wordpress.com/posts/?number=2
```

To obtain, in response, quoting the [doc page](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/get/sites/%24site/posts/), three parameters:

- **found** (int), the total number of posts found that match the request
- **posts** (array), an array of post objects.
- **meta** (object), meta data

So you may create a free and simple blog on [wordpress.com](http://wordpress.com) and access its post via the above mentioned APIs. Therefore, you won't require any database on your local site.
Still, some simple **PHP**, or maybe **Javascript** is required, but I really can't imagine how one could avoid preprocessing in any non static website, as a blog is. For example, you may use [simple **GET** requests](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to use the APIs (see this doc as an example of how to do it).